# how to change vuetify default breakpoint for a component?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I want to ovverride the vuetify default breakpoint for certain file. i have created a styles folder on my source directory and inside styles folder i created variables.scss file. inside variables scss file my code is like this.

`$grid-breakpoints: (
        xs: 0,
        sm: 650px,
        md: 1190px,
        lg: 1100px,
        xl: 1200px
);`

**it's overriding breakpoint for my entire project. but i just want to override the breakpoint for only some component.**

**is there any way i can achieve that?**

Answer (score 0):

The idea of breakpoint is resizing all parts of a page together.
If you won't custom  breakpoint for only one component just write default media queries in CSS like there https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media